# Display a Flyout in a row?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I've a list of content inside a `ListView`, each item contains an id, this id will passed into an event that's should show the details of the row clicked inside the Flyout. Now I've this situation:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5" x:Name="FlyoutRow"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

so how you can see in the main grid I've defined a `row` called `FlyoutRow`, this row is not visible at startup but only when the user click on the event avaialble in the `ListView`.

Now the problem's that the row height is 5 so the `Flyout` will never appear to the user, is possible expand the row keeping the `Flyout` animation?

This is my implementation of the `Flyout`:

```
<Controls:Flyout x:Name="Flyout" Header="Flyout" Grid.Row="1">

</Controls:Flyout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Row height to Auto. Then use storyboard that will chage flyout height.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Maximize">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="5" To="100" Storyboard.TargetName="FL">
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="Minimize">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="100" To="5" Storyboard.TargetName="FL">
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="292*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="FlyoutRow"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="View">
            <ListView.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListView.SelectionChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Maximize}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListView.LostFocus">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Minimize}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ListView.Triggers>
            <ListBoxItem Content="First item" Tag="Some information from first item"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Second item" Tag="Some information from second item"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Third item" Tag="Some information from third item"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Fourth item" Tag="Some information from fourth item"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Fifth item" Tag="Some information from fifth item"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Sixth item" Tag="Some information from sixth item"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Seventh item" Tag="Some information from Seventh item"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Eigth item" Tag="Some information from eith item"/>
        </ListView>
        <controls:Flyout Grid.Row="1" Width="517" x:Name="FL" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsOpen="True">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" Background="#FF74FF24"/>
        </controls:Flyout>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem, 'cause I need to have 5px space, if I set auto this space will be lost

Comment: Add one more row with 5px height.

Comment: Then apply Storyboard to Row's height and set flyout.VerticalAligment=Stretch, Height=Auto to add 5px space you can set Margin

Comment: the problem's that this will set the height to all controls